# How to make a back to site banner

Tags: html, css, web, banner

I am new to HTML and CSS but I am picking it up very quickly, so I apologize in advance if what I am asking is too complicated or can't be done.

I would like to redirect people to other website but I want a banner to follow so that at anytime they can return back to my website.

For example this website

http://www.idvanish.com/browse.php?u=X1A0ZvbwFuQeXuIhjUwneCmB&b=31

It has this banner with a url that follows you to what ever website you type on it. I would like something similar but instead of a URL code just a simple button that follows you and at any time you click it to return back to the website.

Thanks to all those who can help me :D Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Thats ease for the redirect use meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://new-site.com/">
```

And to back if you want the button to be at the side use this:

HTML:

```
<a href="old-site.com">Go to old site</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    position: fixed;
    right:0;
}
```

I think this is what you want.

If it is not please say

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://www.yoursite.com"><img src="thisImageSource"/></a>
```

this line will add a clickable banner to your html code.